# how to process unknown quantity of POST variables into an email message upon form submit

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I am new to php so here goes...

I am trying to output all items ordered from my SESSION variables into input values with a function so that I can process them with a form submit. Now the input fields are created successfully and all ok.
here is the code

```
function list_cart_items() {
    $num =0;
    $total=0;
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value!=0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $iget = mysql_query('SELECT id,name,price FROM items WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
            while ($iget_row = mysql_fetch_array($iget)) {
            $num ++;
            $total += number_format(($iget_row['price']*$value),2);
            echo "<tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='order_item".$num."' value='".$num."' size='2' maxlength='2'>
            <td><input type='text' name='order_qty_item".$num."' value='".number_format($value,1)."' size='3' maxlength='3'>
            <td><input type='text' name='order_name_item".$num."' value='".$iget_row['name']."' size='30' maxlength='30'>
            <td><input type='text' name='order_value_item".$num."' value='R ".number_format(($iget_row['price']*$value), 2)."' size='6' maxlength='6'>
            </tr>";
        }   
        }
    }
}
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><b>Order Total</b></td><td></td><td colspan='2'><b>R ".$total."</b></td></tr>";
```

Here is the code of the actual form creation with submit button

```
    echo "<div id='shoppingcart'><form action='' method='POST'>";
    echo "<table class='checkout'><caption><b>Shopping Cart</b></caption>";
    **list_cart_items();**
    echo "<div id='information'>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Name and Surname:</th><td colspan='3'><input type='text' size='45' maxlength='50' name='Contact' id='Contact'></td><tr>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Telephone number:</th><td colspan='3'><input type='text' size='15' maxlength='12' name='Telephone' id='Telephone'></td><tr>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Delivery Address:</th><td colspan='3'><textarea rows='8' cols='45' id='address' name='address'>Enter Address Here:</textarea></td><tr>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Instructions:</th><td colspan='3'><textarea rows='8' cols='45' id='instructions' name='instructions'></textarea></td><tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan='5' align='center'><button type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' style='border: 0; background: transparent'>
   <img src='images/buynow.jpg' class='button' alt='submit'/>
   </button></td><tr>";
   echo "</form></div></table></div>";
```

Now comes the million dollor question , since I do not know how many products have been selected and ordered , I do not know what the maximum value is for my SESSION['cart_X'];
thus I do not know how many input fields have been created on my form.

What I am trying to do is to process each value in my POST array successfully and output that into a $emailbody (Order needs to be processed and emailed)
I have tried playing around with the **foreach ($_POST as $entry){ print $entry."
";}**
but no success

here is the code ..

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $orderno = session_id();
    $contact = $_POST['Contact'];
    $telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $instructions = $_POST['instructions'];
    //Here I need to catch every POST variable (all items given as input fields in my form) values
    $to = "orders@t.co.za";
    $subject = "Order received via website";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'To: Johan <schoeman.jj@gmail.com>'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Order via Web <orders@triumphant.co.za>'."\r\n";
    $emailbody = "Order number :".$orderno."<br>
        Contact Person: ".$contact."<br>
    Telephone number: ".$telephone."<br>
    Delivery Address: ".$address."<br>
    Instructions: ".$instructions."<br>
//Here I need to include every POST order item
```

Comment: do a `foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {` just like you did for the session array.

Comment: Need to have the field name as array such as <input name='product[]' /> Then in the $_POST['product'] you will have an array of the products. Same way you can get elements that can repeat.

Comment: it seems that you dont submit your cart entries via post. Thats the reason why you arent successful by try `foreach($_POST...` but it seems that the cart is already stored in $_SESSION, so you can do `foreach($_SESSION...` like you did by creating your field inputs in your first posted code.

Comment: No steven, because you will need to be able to change the items in the cart before post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont add `$num` to the name of the input, but create an array:

```
function list_cart_items() {
    // .....
        <td><input type='text' name='order_item[]' value='".$num."' size='2' maxlength='2'>
        <td><input type='text' name='order_qty_item[]' value='".number_format($value,1)."' size='3' maxlength='3'>
        <td><input type='text' name='order_name_item[]' value='".$iget_row['name']."' size='30' maxlength='30'>
        <td><input type='text' name='order_value_item[]' value='R ".number_format(($iget_row['price']*$value), 2)."' size='6' maxlength='6'>
```

They you will receive those variables as arrays in your `$_POST`. Just loop through them.

```
$emailbody = "Order number :".$orderno."<br>
    Contact Person: ".$contact."<br>
    Telephone number: ".$telephone."<br>
    Delivery Address: ".$address."<br>
    Instructions: ".$instructions."<br>";

foreach($_POST['order_item'] as $key => $value) {
    // Add to $emailbody (edit line below to match your markup)
    $emailbody .= '' . $_POST['order_item'][$key] . ' ' . $_POST['order_qty_item'][$key] . '<br />'; //etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers , much appreciated.how do I then catch these values from the for($_POST array and output them into the $emailbody

Comment: See my second block of code. Those 4 are the variables. Just add a line to add content to the email body. (edited my answer)

Comment: Hi Stijn Martens , Thanks again .. I am totally in the dark here .. to catch a POST variable .. I understand you should set a Svariable = $_POST['variable'] and then you can make use of the $variable in your $emailbody , does this mean I can directly take $_POST['order_item'][$key] as my variable in my $emailbody ... and if so how would it know that there is more than one that needs to be included , as the for loop does not work in the $emailbody

Comment: You don't really need to set a variable like `$variable = $_POST['variable']`, you can directly use the `$_POST['variable']`.
(edited my answer)

Comment: Awesome !!! thanks now I understand it 100% one problem though :-).. I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS, expecting ';' in C:\wamp\www\Triumph\cart.php on line 40   and line 40 reads   -   40   for($_POST['order_item'] as $key => $value) {             copied the code exactly as you stated , somewhere I am missing something;

Comment: It should be `foreach` instead of `for`, my bad.

Comment: Stijn Martens you are officialy my HERO !! thanks dude ! if you ever find yourself in Cape town - South Africa .. look me up so I can buy you a beer